# Expectation of x/√(x²+2px+1) under Normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, convergence, moments, taylor-series

I'm need to find (or at least approximate) as a function of $p$, the expectation under $x \sim Normal(0,1)$ of:

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2px+1}},\hspace{1em}\textrm{where}-1<p<1$$

[Wolfram Alpha tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+expansion+of+%28x%29%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2%2B2*p*x%2B1%29) that the Taylor expansion is just the Legendre Polynomials:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n P_{n-1}(-p) $$

However, if I plug in the Normal moments $\mathbb{E}(x^n)=(n-1)!!$ for even $n$, the series seems really divergent:

$$\mathbb{E}[f(x)] = 1!! P_1(-p) + 3!! P_3(-p) + 5!! P_5(-p) + 7!!P_7(-p) + \ldots$$

It seems like the expectation should be well-defined. Is there an analytical solution, and if not how can I approximate it?

P.S. I also need to calculate $\mathbb{E}[xf(x)]$, which I'm having the same problem with.

Huge thanks to anybody who can point me in the right direction!
~ Luke

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\int g(x) p(x)dx$, where $X\sim p(x)$. I don’t remember integration methods well enough to say how to do that computation, but I would expect integration by parts to come up.

Comment: Since you know the distribution of $x$ you could use I think Monte Carlo approximation of the expected value

Comment: If the expectation in fact exists, define $g(p) = E[f(X)]$. It is easy to show that $g$ is an odd function. Hence, $g(0) = 0$, and you can focus only on $p\,\in\,(0,1)$.

Comment: I would *hope* that series would diverge! The expansion is a power series around $0$ and its radius of convergence cannot extend any further than the nearest pole, which will be at $x=-p\pm i\sqrt{1-p^2},$ a distance of only $1$ from the origin.  Since the Normal distribution has support beyond the interval $(-1,1),$ this approach shouldn't succeed.

Comment: BTW, how accurate does the approximation need to be?  For which values of $p$?

Comment: Ah right! That makes sense @whuber, thanks!

It's okay if the approximation isn't especially accurate. I can integrate numerically or use an MC approximation to get an accurate answer (as suggested by Dave and Fiodor1234) but it would be very helpful to find a fairly simple expression (in p). For example, is it possible to express the integral as something like a taylor series in p, which is accurate at p=0 but less accurate at p=±1?

Comment: A rough approximation based on no analysis at all is that the square root of the negative expectation is approximately $0.35$ times $\Phi^{-1}((1+p)/2)$ for $p\ge 0;$ for negative $p,$ use symmetry  ($\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF).  The quest for a Taylor series looks hopeless, because the expectation has (extraordinarily sharp) poles at $p=\pm 1.$

Comment: Okay great @whuber thank you! How did you get to $\Phi^{-1}((1+p)/2)$? Sorry if I'm being slow in understanding the steps, I feel like I'm just missing a trick here.

Comment: The idea is to reparameterize $p.$ The symmetry suggests parameterizing $q=(1+p)/2$ as $q = F(\theta)$ for some distribution $F$ and $\theta\in\mathbb{R};$ using a Normal distribution will take care of the behavior of the poles near $p=\pm 1.$  A plot of the expectation against $\theta$ is curvilinear and--almost miraculously--is nearly linearized with a square root transformation, especially for $|q|\gt 1.$ The $-0.35$ is an empirical estimate of its slope.